# How I can handle with error about entered size of string exceeds the set size of char array?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I need some kind of error handler if I enter a string larger than the set size.

```
cout << "Enter long of the string" << endl;
        cin >> N;
        char* st = new char[N];
        char* st1 = new char[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            *(st1 + i) = ' ';
        }
        cout << "Enter string in the end put 0,without whitespace in the end." << endl;
        cin.getline(st, N, '0');
```

Comment: why not use std::string?

Comment: Next I need split string by words and than make a new string with words since X to Y from the old one. I think that it is more simple, if work with char array.

Comment: What do think you can do with a char array, that you can't do with a `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

First some comments.

- Do not use C-Style arrays in C++ (like `char data[N]`)
- Always use `std::string` for strings
- Never use `char` arrays for strings
- Never ever use raw pointers for owned memory in C++
- Neally never use `new` in C++
- Avoid using pointer arithmetic with raw pointers pointing to owned memory

So, you should rethink your design. Start doing it correctly in the first place.

To answer you concrete question: If you read the documentation of the [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), then you can see that

> count-1 characters have been extracted (in which case setstate(failbit) is executed).

So, the failbit will be set. You can check this with

```
if (std::cin.rdstate() == std::ios_base::failbit)
```

But as you can also read in the documentation

> Extracts characters from stream until end of line or the specified delimiter delim.

So, it will not work, as you expect, It will try to read until 0 has been read. I think it will not work for you.

You also need to delete the newed memory. Otherwise, you are creating a memory hole. Look at you example again and try it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    size_t N;
    std::cout << "Enter maximum length of the string\n";
    std::cin >> N;
    char* st = new char[N];
    char* st1 = new char[N];
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < N; ++i) {
        *(st1 + i) = ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "Enter string in the end put 0, without whitespace in the end.\n";
    std::cin.getline(st, N, '0');

    if (std::cin.rdstate() == std::ios_base::failbit) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "\nError: Wrong string entered\n\n";
    }

    delete[] st;
    delete[] st1;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Solution for all your problems:** Use `std::string` and `std::getline`

---